# How to determine dropdown should show upward or downward direction

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, html

I tried to design a dropdown component.

So far I faced an issue that the dropdown list is too long, so I keen to display it as the upward direction. I know Bootstrap has the same feature, but I want to do it my own.
Any suggestions or keywords?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I don't use any library. Just refer the Bootstrap has achieved the purpose.
These pictures are just examples
[image: downward]

[image: upward]

Comment: no. I am not using bootstrap. I tried to do it myself

Comment: Can you please add your current CSS/HTML code?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what Bootstrap did, they were checking if the dropdown-menu height is less than the rest of the screen. Below is what I did.

```
let style = 'bottom';
let element = document.getElementById('myId');
if (window.innerHeight - element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < element.scrollHeight){
     style = 'top'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a Bootstrap component:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

The default behaviour is to open on the bottom. Opening on top is determined by setting the `.dropup` element as the parent of `.dropdown-menu` element. This is described in Bootstrap's documentation under [dropup variation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation).

Bootstrap relies on js and [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) for the behavioural aspects of dropdowns.

If you don't want to use Bootstrap, use its lead as a reference or rely on one of the million free tutorials/examples available online. Here are a few examples.

CSS only solution:

https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

JS:

https://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/fcaDw

http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/javascript-drop-down-menu-examples/

Comment: Sorry mate. I don't want to use any library to achieve the purpose.

Comment: Edited answer with a few examples. If you're not using a library it all depends on your requirements. There's a bunch of free examples online.

Comment: I already had a dropdown panel. However, the dropdown list is too long and I don't want to let my main page scrollable. So I want to show upward direction if there are no enough height to display

Comment: That requires dynamically calculating elements and viewport dimensions. Take a look at https://popper.js.org/. I'd say don't reinvent the wheel, but if you still want to do it, you're gonna need to break some stone with the tools of your choosing ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me think about it.